# Can anyone explain how this code prints 1 to 10?

Tags: java, recursion

Can anyone explain how this code prints 1 to 10???

```
class demo
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        display(10);    
    }
    private static void display(int n) 
    {
        if (n > 1) 
        {
            display(n - 1);
        }
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to do it on paper (start with a small number like 2 or 3). You will understand better.

Comment: I am only able to understand till it prints 1, after that it is not clear how execution takes place.

Comment: Just read the code line by line. And keep track o the value of `n` on paper. Or you can try to step trough the code with a debugger and inspect the variables as you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a recursive call to display method. Here the argument value passed to display method is stored in a stack. when the if condition fails then the value of n if poped from stack and printed by line "System.out.println(n)".
 In other words, Every time display method called by passing a number, the number will be stored in a stack so that when code will come out of recursion, it will use that number from stack.

Doing the dry run you can see when the value 1 is passed to display method the if condition fails and the next line prints the value 1 then 2 will be printed which was in stack and so on it will print up to 10 which is the first value passed.

Comment: Tadah! :) Nice answer Shubham!

Answer (score 0):

So the main method runs the display method and passes a value of 10. Then, the value is checked to see if it is greater than 1 (which it is). Next. the display method is called again with a value of n-1, which is 9 in this case. Lastly, 10 is printed out.

Now 9 goes through the same cycle. 9 is greater than 1 and display is called with a value of n-1, which is now 8. 9 is printed out and now 8 goes through the display method. This continues to happen until the value is 1 in which case 1 is not greater than 1 and 1 is printed out and the program exits.

This is called a recursive method if you would like to look into it more.